# Using Gatsby `createResolvers` to set default image if GraphQL returns null?

Tags: wordpress, graphql, schema, gatsby

I'm working on a [gatsby](/questions/tagged/gatsby) site using `gatsby-source-wordpress` to source posts for the blog. However, if any of the WordPress posts do not include a featured image this causes the build to fail. I understand that this is expected behavior.

### Here is the build error I am seeing:

```sh
  29 |           {posts.map(({ node: post }, index) => ( 
  30 |             <li key={post.id} {...post}>
> 31 |               <Img fixed={post.featured_media.localFile.childImageSharp.fixed} />
     |                                               ^
  32 |               <p>
  33 |                 <Link to={`/insights/${post.slug}`}>
  34 |                   {post.title}

  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'localFile' of null
```

This is caused by the resulting query, which is returning a null result in the second node because there is no featured image on the post:

```sh
{
  "data": {
    "allWordpressPost": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "28ec9054-5b05-5f94-adcb-dcbfc14659b1",
            "featured_media": {
              "id": "f12d613b-e544-560b-a86f-cd0a7f87801e",
              "localFile": {
                "id": "7fca2893-ff80-5270-9765-d17d3dc21ac2",
                "url": "https://www.mycustomdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/some-featured-image.jpg"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "91a236ed-39d5-5efc-8bed-290d8344b660",
            "featured_media": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### How I would like to fix:

As an ideal solution, I would like to use schema customization to set a default image if there is no featured image in WordPress. But I am at a total loss how to correctly do so. I am working from [this documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/) to guide me, but I'm just not getting my head wrapped around it properly.

### A similar working example:

*Tag* data is similar to featured images in that the query returns null if the post has no tags. However I am able to set a default `undefined` tag using `createResolvers` like so:

```js
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
  const resolvers = {
    wordpress__POST: {
      tags: {
        resolve(source, args, context, info) {
          const { tags } = source
          if (tags === null || (Array.isArray(tags) && !tags.length)) {
            return [
              {
                id: 'undefined',
                name: 'undefined',
                slug: 'undefined',
              }
            ]
          } else {
            return info.originalResolver(source, args, context, info)
          }
        },
      },
    },
  }
  createResolvers(resolvers)
}
```

And this works as shown in the following query results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allWordpressPost": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "28ec9054-5b05-5f94-adcb-dcbfc14659b1",
            "tags": [
              {
                "id": "undefined"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "91a236ed-39d5-5efc-8bed-290d8344b660",
            "tags": [
              {
                "id": "50449e18-bef7-566a-a3eb-9f7990084afb"
              },
              {
                "id": "8635ff58-2997-510a-9eea-fe2b88f30781"
              },
              {
                "id": "97029bee-4dec-5198-95af-8464393f71e3"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### What I tried for images (isn't working...)

When it comes to nested nodes and image files I'm at a total loss. I am heading in the following direction [based on this article](https://dev.to/nevernull/how-to-handle-images-and-make-use-of-gatsby-image-guide-to-gatsby-wordpress-starter-advanced-with-previews-i18n-and-more-g9b) and [this code example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-gatsby-source-graphql/gatsby-node.js), but so far it isn't working:

```js
exports.createResolvers = ({
  actions,
  cache,
  createNodeId,
  createResolvers,
  store,
  reporter,
}) => {
  const { createNode } = actions
  const resolvers = {
    wordpress__POST: {
      featured_media: {
        type: `File`,
        resolve(source, args, context, info) {
          return createRemoteFileNode({
            url: 'https://www.mycustomdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/placeholder.png',
            store,
            cache,
            createNode,
            createNodeId,
            reporter,
          })
        },
      },
    },
  }
  createResolvers(resolvers)
}
```

I realize the above code does not have an `if else` statement, so the expectation is that *all* featured images would be replaced by the placeholder image. However the resulting GraphQL query is unaffected (as shown at top).

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I can't seem to wrap my head around what information I can find out there.

Answer (score 1):

> WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'localFile' of null

`'localFile' of null` means that nulled is a parent of `localfile` - `featured_media` ... you can see that in results:

> "featured_media": null

... so you're trying to fix `localfile` while you should work on `featured_media` level

## why?

You can easily render conditionally [in react] what you need (placeholde, component) on nulled nodes ... why at all you're trying to fix graphql response?

Comment: that's a good point, I can just render conditionally; was just looking at (more complicated) alternatives. And yes, meant to focus on `featured_media` not `localFile`.

Comment: other scenario - second client/app for the same API or even another language version - overwritting defaults? detecting 'placeholders' in data? API changes - detecting fails, too - null is safer, more universal